# Mean Sickness Absence at different company sites statically significant ? T-Test, Z-Test?

Tags: t-test, z-test

I'm relatively new to stats so apologies if this is rather trivial but I cannot find an answer (I work in the workforce information dept of a largish company). We have 10 sites, and I calculate the %sickness absence rate per month for each site, going back a number of years.

Site 1 shows marginally but consistently high sickness absence rate than all the others. My boss has asked me if this is statistically significant and stated...

"Hypothesis: site 1 sick absence rate is significantly higher than the other sites" and went on to say "If I can prove that our results are not statistically significant to say a 5% level, then we can move on and it's not an issues". He went on to suggest we could use a variant of the T-test.

My questions are: 1/ A graph The of site against the other shows consistently marginal higher absenteeism compared to the rest so is his questions meaningful anyway? 2/ If a valid question what test(s) could I use? 3/ Intuitively how do I think about this problem, presumably if the difference between site 1 and the  other sites is not statically significant then that is implying site 1's sickness absence could drift down to that of the other sites?

Any help much appreciated, Thanks, Oscar

Answer (score 0):

The null hypothesis should be that all 10 sites have the same (population) sickness absence rates, and then the alternative hypothesis is that all 10 are not the same.

Some one of the 10 is sure to have a higher rate over
the $n=12y$ monthly rates observed over the last $y$ years.
The *statistical* question is whether that highest rate is "significantly" greater than the others. A *managerial* question would be whether the differences among the sites are large enough to be of practical importance, and if so, what may be the cause of the disparity.

In the framework I discuss above, assuming that the
rates are nearly normally distributed, one correct test
would be a two-factor ANOVA, in which there are 10 levels of the Site factor. The second factor would be
Month with $12y$ levels. (Some people would call the months 'blocks'.)

Below are simulated data for 5 years (60 months). 
Site means and standard deviations are as follows:

```
Columns: Site

     1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9     10    All

  9.69  10.06  10.23   9.97  10.30   9.63  10.04  10.01  10.03  10.10  10.01
 2.251  2.072  1.742  2.281  1.964  1.557  1.870  1.949  2.271  2.053  2.009
    60     60     60     60     60     60     60     60     60     60    600

Cell Contents:  Abs  :  Mean
                Abs  :  Standard deviation
                        Count
```

The highest average absence rate is 10.30 and the lowest is 9.63. An ANOVA shows that
these are not surprisingly different:  The P-value for Site is 0.75 > 0.05.

```
Analysis of Variance for Abs

Source   DF        SS     MS     F      P
Site      9    24.009  2.668  0.65  0.753
Mo       59   215.915  3.660  0.89  0.699
Error   531  2176.568  4.099
Total   599  2416.492
```

*Notes:* (1) I simulated my data with rates for all 600 months at each Site to be normal with mean 10
and standard deviation 2. (2) If your data seem to be far from normal, you might investigate
whether a Friedman nonparametric test is appropriate.

Comment: Hi BruceET, Thank you for that very well explained answer, much appreciated, Oscar